# Delete latest entry in SQL Server without using datetime or ID

Tags: sql-server, delete-row

I have a basic SQL Server delete script that goes:

```
Delete from tableX 
where colA = ? and colB = ?;
```

In `tableX`, I do not have any columns indicating sequential IDs or timestamp; just `varchar`. I want to delete the latest entry that was inserted, and I do not have access to the row number from the insert script. `TOP` is not an option because it's random. Also, this particular table does not have a primary key, and it's not a matter of poor design. Is there any way I can do this? I recall mysql being able to call something like `max(row_number)` and also something along the lines of limit one.

Comment: For this to work you must have a column you can use to determine order. It sounds like you don't have a way to determine the "latest" row. You are stuck here because the design will not support this.

Comment: Any operation that depends on row ordering must have an ordering column.

Comment: It's weird, I've seen this question asked a number of times recently, but can't find them in Google results.   Maybe the OPs deleted them.

Comment: @SeanLange and Zoff Dino, thanks for your comments. I understand the constraints and have described them in the above. However, I'm still trying my luck to see if there's a possible workaround.

Comment: There is no workaround. You are trying to identify rows when there is nothing that defines "when". If you don't have the information you have zero ability to do this.

Comment: @SeanLange, I note your opinion. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ROW_NUMBER` exists in SQL Server, too, but it must be used with an `OVER (order_by_clause)`. So... in your case it's impossible for you unless you come up with another sorting algo.

[MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734(v=sql.110).aspx)

Edit: (Examples for George from MSDN ... I'm afraid his company has a Firewall rule that blocks MSDN)

SQL-Code

```
USE AdventureWorks2012; 
GO
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SalesYTD DESC) AS Row, 
    FirstName, LastName, ROUND(SalesYTD,2,1) AS "Sales YTD" 
FROM Sales.vSalesPerson
WHERE TerritoryName IS NOT NULL AND SalesYTD <> 0;
```

Output

```
Row FirstName    LastName               SalesYTD
--- -----------  ---------------------- -----------------
1   Linda        Mitchell               4251368.54
2   Jae          Pak                    4116871.22
3   Michael      Blythe                 3763178.17
4   Jillian      Carson                 3189418.36
5   Ranjit       Varkey Chudukatil      3121616.32
6   José         Saraiva                2604540.71
7   Shu          Ito                    2458535.61
8   Tsvi         Reiter                 2315185.61
9   Rachel       Valdez                 1827066.71
10  Tete         Mensa-Annan            1576562.19
11  David        Campbell               1573012.93
12  Garrett      Vargas                 1453719.46
13  Lynn         Tsoflias               1421810.92
14  Pamela       Ansman-Wolfe           1352577.13
```

---

Returning a subset of rows

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
WITH OrderedOrders AS
(
    SELECT SalesOrderID, OrderDate,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderDate) AS RowNumber
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader 
) 
SELECT SalesOrderID, OrderDate, RowNumber  
FROM OrderedOrders 
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 50 AND 60;
```

---

Using ROW_NUMBER() with PARTITION

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
SELECT FirstName, LastName, TerritoryName, ROUND(SalesYTD,2,1),
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TerritoryName ORDER BY SalesYTD DESC) AS Row
FROM Sales.vSalesPerson
WHERE TerritoryName IS NOT NULL AND SalesYTD <> 0
ORDER BY TerritoryName;
```

Output

```
FirstName  LastName             TerritoryName        SalesYTD      Row
---------  -------------------- ------------------   ------------  ---
Lynn       Tsoflias             Australia            1421810.92    1
José       Saraiva              Canada               2604540.71    1
Garrett    Vargas               Canada               1453719.46    2
Jillian    Carson               Central              3189418.36    1
Ranjit     Varkey Chudukatil    France               3121616.32    1
Rachel     Valdez               Germany              1827066.71    1
Michael    Blythe               Northeast            3763178.17    1
Tete       Mensa-Annan          Northwest            1576562.19    1
David      Campbell             Northwest            1573012.93    2
Pamela     Ansman-Wolfe         Northwest            1352577.13    3
Tsvi       Reiter               Southeast            2315185.61    1
Linda      Mitchell             Southwest            4251368.54    1
Shu        Ito                  Southwest            2458535.61    2
Jae        Pak                  United Kingdom       4116871.22    1
```

Comment: Could you give an example using 'over'?

Answer (score 2):

Your current table design does not allow you to determine the latest entry. YOu have no field to sort on to indicate which record was added last.

You need to redesign or pull that information from the audit tables. If you have a database without audit tables, you might have to find a tool to read the transaction logs and it will be a very time-consuming and expensive process. Or if you know the date the records you want to remove were added, you could possibly use a backup from just before this happened to find the records that were added. Just be awwre that you might be looking at records changed after this date that you want to keep.

If you need to do this on a regular basis instead of one-time to fix some bad data, then you need to properly design your database to include an identity field and possibly a dateupdated field (maintained through a trigger) or audit tables. (In my opinion no database containing information your company is depending on should be without audit tables, one of the many reasons why you should never allow an ORM to desgn a database, but I digress.) If you need to know the order records were added to a table, it is your responsiblity as the developer to create that structure. Databases only store what is deisnged for tehm to store, if you didn't design it in, then it is not available easily or at all

Comment: Thanks. It's not a matter of 'poorly' designed tables. There's a good rationale why this table does not have an ID column or even a primary key. In any case, I'm looking for a work around for this and I'm pretty sure it's possible. We'll see how this thread goes.

Comment: There are very few times that a table with no primary key makes sense. Do you at least have a clustered index?

Comment: Well. This **is** a workaround - set up and maintain audit tables using triggers. Why not. The structure of the original table is not changed, the missing info is recorded in the audit tables.

Answer (score 0):

If `(colA +'_'+ colB)`   can not be dublicate  try this.

```
 declare @delColumn nvarchar(250)

    set @delColumn = (select top 1   DeleteColumn from (
    select (colA +'_'+ colB)  as DeleteColumn ,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY colA DESC) as Id from tableX  
    )b
    order by Id desc
    )

delete  from tableX where  (colA +'_'+ colB) =@delColumn
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, the values of colA+colB are not unique. Will still give this a shot though.

Comment: This would still give you a ramndom record to delte not necessarlity the latest one.

Comment: @HILGEM If (colA +'_'+ colB) can not be dublicate my script should work. check this pls.

http://i61.tinypic.com/29fcqz4.png

Comment: @memettayanc unfortunately as mentioned, the values of colA+colB is not unique. In other words, can be duplicated.